# Merge specific commit of github package into github package used in my project

Tags: git, github

I would like to make use of [this tslint commit](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/pull/1060/files#r58076945). I don't think it got merged to master.

I tried editing my **package.json** `devDependencies` to:

```
"tslint": "git@github.com:palantir/tslint.git#598a21dc7c498133ef6c40f58956c65c31b5d6ac",
```

It didn't work but it would also no longer contain the new tslint features since it is an old commit so I don't think it would be a good solution.

How can I get that commit into my version of tslint?

Comment: I idin't get the end of your comment. You need to fork https://github.com/palantir/tslint, clone that fork, apply the cheery-pick there and push.

Comment: I have edited the answer to propose a more complete way to get that pull-request into a GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider cherry-picking that one commit into your own repository, and reference the new HEAD SHA1 in your package.json

[`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) allows you to apply the changes of that commit to your code.

Since you don't own [`github.com/palantir/tslint`](https://github.com/palantir/tslint), you need to [fork it](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/), clone that fork locally, and then

```
cd /path/to/my/local/clone
git remote add upstream https://github.com/palantir/tslint
git config --add remote.upstream.fetch "+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/upstream/pr/*"
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
```

Now, you can actually merge the `pr` ('pull-request') branch instead of cherry-picking one or several commits:

```
git checkout pr/1060
git checkout master
git merge pr/1060
git push
```

And you can now reference the merge commit you just created and pushed.

Comment: If you have cloned a fork, git checkout master should work

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins No: in your local clone, you need to import palantir. And fetch its pr branch.

Comment: Thanks just cleared my comments to keep it concise. What will the package.json import be? At the moment it is `"tslint": "3.14.0",`

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins the url of your fork plus the SHA1 you pushed to it.